# How to parse a string to insert a row into a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, savings_amount, company) VALUES (' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ', '1', ' .    $row['product_id'] . ', ' . $saving . ', ' . $row['company'] . ')";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connection );
    if(! $retval ){
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());

}
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
```

Trying to a string to insert a row into a table. Keep getting syntax errors.

Current error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: use prepared statement so it is easier to read.

Comment: Downvoted, as you deleted a question whilst a comments conversation was in flow. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always prepare your variables in a good manner like below that is a good practice:

```
    $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $productId = $row['product_id'];
    $company = $row['saving'];
    $categoryId = 1;
    $savingAmount = $saving;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, 
    savings_amount, company) 
    VALUES ('$userId', 'categoryId', '$productId', '$savingAmount', '$company')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing [quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php),

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, savings_amount,   
        company) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', '1', '" .    $row['product_id'] .  
        "', '" . $saving . "', '" . $row['company'] . "')";
```

**Warning:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

You concatinated your string wrong. What you want is this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, savings_amount, company) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] ." ', '1', '" .    $row['product_id'] . "', '" . $saving . "', '" . $row['company'] . "')";
```

Alternatively you could simple wrap it in curly brackets (`{}`) like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, savings_amount, company) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['user_id']} ', '1', '{$row['product_id']}', '$saving ', '{$row['company']}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, savings_amount, company) VALUES (' $_SESSION[user_id] ', '1', ' $row[product_id] ', ' $saving ', ' $row[company] ')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not proper. try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, 
        savings_amount, company) VALUES ('". $_SESSION['user_id']."',1,
        '". $row['product_id'] ."', '". $saving . "', '". $row['company'] ."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quotes to end a string

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_saving_plans (user_id, catergory_id, product_id, savings_amount, company) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', '1', '" .    $row['product_id'] . "', '" . $saving . "', '" . $row['company'] . "')";
```